# change the image of a toolbarbutton

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

How to dynamically change the image of a toolbarbutton with javascript?

I try this :

```
<toolbarbutton id=""  oncommand="this.style.listStyleImage= 'url(green-chrono.png)';alert('boom');" label="Menu-button" type="menu-button" style="list-style-image: url(chrono.png);">
        <menupopup id="edit-popup1">
            <menuitem id="toto" label="Accéder à la pointeuse"/>
            <menuitem id="recap" label="Accéder au récapitulatif des heures"/>
        </menupopup>
    </toolbarbutton>
```

But it doesn't work, when I click on the button, the picture disappears.

images and xul file are in the same directory.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Basically you code works for me but you have added 2 images for one command. Please check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_toolbar_buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the approach is correct but you are using a relative URL. Relative URLs are resolved relative to the stylesheet - so if `chrome://myextension/skin/style.css` uses the relative URL `green-chrono.png` the browser will load `chrome://myextension/skin/green-chrono.png`. In the case that you have here there is no external stylesheet however meaning that the URL will be resolved relative to the XUL document. I guess that this XUL code is located in the browser window - meaning that the URL `chrome://browser/content/green-chrono.png` is loaded and it doesn't exist of course. The solution: specify the absolute URL instead of a relative one, e.g.:

```
this.style.listStyleImage = 'url(chrome://myextension/skin/green-chrono.png)';
```